# Is the `std::sort` function unstable?

Tags: c++, sorting, c++17, std

Just wanted to confirm if what I am thinking is right or wrong.
According to the definition:

> A sorting algorithm is said to be stable if two objects with
> equal or same keys appear in the same order in sorted
> output as they appear in the input array to be sorted.

Now in [std::sort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/) in the standard library, returning false when two elements are equal is a must. Hence, is it safe to say that the sorting algorithm used is unstable?

Comment: [What's the difference between “STL” and “C++ Standard Library”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205491/whats-the-difference-between-stl-and-c-standard-library)

Comment: As far as I know, nobody has discovered or invented an O(n*log(n)) in-place stable sorting algorithm yet.

Comment: @molbdnilo I think [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Variants) mentions some. And is `std::sort` guaranteed in-place, or why did you say that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Now in the sort function in STL, returning false when two elements are equal is a must. Hence, is it safe to say that the sorting algorithm used is unstable?

No, that’s completely unrelated.

As a matter of fact, `std::sort` isn’t guaranteed to be stable; if you require a stable sort, use [`std::stable_sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_sort).

But the string weak ordering requirement is unrelated, and is the same for both `std::sort` and `std::stable_sort`.

Answer (score 2):

`std::sort()` is not guaranteed to be stable, and in practice it will never be implemented as stable since stable sort is slower. If you need stable sort, use [`std::stable_sort()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_sort).

Answer (score 2):

> returning false when two elements are equal is a must.

That doesn't make the difference between a stable and a non-stable sorting algorithm.

The two major standard sorting algorithms are [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) and [`std::stable_sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_sort). The first is not guaranteed to be stable, the latter is. Both require `<` or the comparator that is used as predicate to implement a [strict weak ordering](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare) (which implies `a < a` is `false` for any `a`).

Answer (score -2):

Check the C++ reference at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/  which clearly indicates it to be not stable

Comment: It’s unstable, but not for the reason OP thinks.

Comment: assume OP did consult documentation before asking, then this answer will not help them. If you assume that they didn't then this should have been a comment